# APFS snapshot specific volume

Tags: macos, apfs

Does anyone know how to make an APFS snapshot of a specific APFS volume?

`tmutil` doesn't seem to have that option and `tmutil snapshot` make snapshots for all APFS volumes.
`diskutil` neither

But for sure it's possible, hopefully there is a tool for this.

Comment: This is not a programming question so it's off-topic here, but it should be fine on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).